# Conjugacy of linear transformations with the same characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, minimal-polynomials, characteristic-polynomial

Consider the following result and proof about conjugacy of linear transformations:

[image: Conjugacy of linear transformations]

Here $E$ and $F$ are $n$-dimensional vector spaces, $\varphi:E\to E$ and $\psi:F\to F$. The $\mu$'s are the minimal polynomials. The proposition referenced says that $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are conjugate if and only if (i) their minimal polynomials have the same prime factors $f_1,\ldots,f_r$ and (ii) $r(f_i(\varphi)^j)=r(f_i(\psi)^j)$ for all $1\le i\le r$ and $j\ge 1$, where $r$ denotes the rank.

My question is: why may we assume that $f$ is a power of a single irreducible *based on what is presented in the proof*? In other words, why "Thus"?

I know the claim is true, but only for reasons that the author has not established at this point in the text, so I feel I am missing something obvious here.

Comment: The kernels $E_i$ are $\varphi$-invariant, and the characteristic polynomial of the restriction $\varphi|_{E_i}$ is just $f_i^{m_i}$.

Comment: @Berci Yes, but how does that follow from what's been shown?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by the presentation: in my book the generalised eigenspace of$~\phi$ for a prime factor $f_i$ of its minimal (or characteristic) polynomial is *defined as* $\ker(f_i[\phi]^{m_i})$, where $m_i$ is the multiplicity of the factor $f_i$ in the minimal polynomial; in other words each $E_i$ would be equal to $\tilde E_i$ by definition. Anyway, the reason one can assume there is just one prime factor, is that $E$ is canonically a direct sum of the generalised eigenspaces; therefore one can find an isomorphism $\psi:E\to F$ intertwining $f$ and $g$ (that is: $\psi\circ f=g\circ\psi$) if and only if one can find individual isomorphisms $\psi_i:E_i\to F_i$ that intertwine the restrictions of $f$ to $E_i$ and of $g$ to $F_i$ (the constructions in both directions are easy). It is then sufficient to focus one the subspaces for one index$~i$.

Comment: In this proof by definition $E_i=\ker(f_i(\varphi)^{k_i})$ (note $k_i$ not $m_i$), and similarly $F_i=\ker(f_i(\psi)^{l_i})$. Anyway, when we take restrictions to $E_i$ and $F_i$, don't we need to know that any prime factor of the characteristic polynomial of a restriction is also a prime factor of the minimal polynomial of the restriction? I know it's true, but the author hasn't established it. I don't see what $E_i=\tilde{E}_i$ and $F_i=\tilde{F}_i$ does for me.

Comment: OK, I missed that the $m_i$ in the OP are multiplicities in to the characteristic polynomial, not minimal which has multiplicities $k_i$, and then indeed $k_i\leq m_i$ is instrumental in linking $E_i$ and $\tilde E_i$. It is fairly immediate from the direct sum decomposition that the minimal polynomial of the restriction of $f$ to $E_i$ is $f_i^{k_i}$: it is an annihilating polynomial of the restriction by definition, and the min.poly cannot be a strict divisor since the min.poly is the lcm of the min.polys of the restrictions.The char.poly of the restriction must similarly be $f_i^{m_i}$.